# How do i build an executable that contain depencies?

Tags: c#, selenium, build, visual-studio-2017, build-dependencies

Visual Studio 2017 is not including dependencies such as NuGet packages, when i build it via the standard option (Build > Publish).

I have a command line project that is dependent on Nuget Packages. The packages are among other Selenium. When i publish the build it gives an error, because Seleium depencies are not present.

I have only tried to publish it in the standard way.

My questions is how i can publish/build the project, so that the Nuget packages are embedded in the executable.

Thanks in advance guys. I hope you can help me.

Comment: it sounds like you want a ["self contained deployment"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#self-contained-deployments-scd) - if you're using .NET Core, it'll be easier...

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for your answer. I found a solution and oddly enough i didnt need to follow those instructions. All i did was select the project root (not the solution) file in the solution explorer and publish it from there. It install to a weird folder in the Appdata folder but it is good enought for me.